# Why SFP+ adapter is warm up when server is powered off?

Tags: hardware

I got a new server: Supermicro with installed ASUS PEB-10G/57840-2S SFP+ network adapter. I was surprised to find out that the adapter is hot when server is powered off, just plugged power cables.

1) Is it ok?

2) How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

If the NIC supports Wake On LAN, it will be linked during S5/soft off. If you don't want that there may be an option to disable WoL in the driver.